# Floor Level for 6x24 tile

Tags: flooring

I am in the process of installing wood like tiles and I was wondering if my floor is level to install those tiles. right now if I use 72" beam box level, it is having 1/8" of uneven floor. So how can I make sure if my floor is ok to install 6"x24" tiles. How to check the floor for leveling.

Thank you,
Nishant Balwan

Answer (score 1):

level isn't as important as flat. ⅛" will not affect the appearance of the tile if you use thin set to install. just use a large tooth comb and feel the edges of your tile as you set them. settle high tile with gentle pressure and expect some clean up in the joints. the wood look is forgiving of small irregularities

Comment: Thank you very much Dennis. So I don't need to pour floor leveler cement right?